# What does “blow a dismount” mean?

Tags: meaning

I heard it in a recent TV episode. Someone walks with a limp (probably a ruptured Achilles' heel), and the doctor mentions that he had the accident “blowing a dismount on a keg stand”.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Blowing" in this sense means getting wrong, screwing up, etc.

"a dismount" is an attempt to get off something ("The part of a routine in which the gymnast detaches from an apparatus.")

I had no idea what a "keg stand" is, but [Wikipedia helped me out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keg_stand).